# Building an OpenCV application in QT Creator

Tags: qt, opencv, compilation

I built OpenCV with CMake under Visual studio 10, copied the binaries to a /bin folder in the opencv directory.  I have a simple OpenCV program with no syntax errors, but I am getting several errors such as "`undefined reference to cv::imread`".  Why is this?

My .pro file has the following appended at the end of it:

```
INCLUDEPATH += C:/opencv/build/include/

LIBS += -LC:/opencv/build/x64/vc10/lib \
-lopencv_core231 \
-lopencv_highgui231 \
-lopencv_imgproc231 \
-lopencv_features2d231 \
-lopencv_calib3d231
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`undefined reference` instead of `unresolved external symbol` means you are probably using MinGW for your application, and you can't use gcc with a VC++ compiled *C++* library.